# validate not working in the html

Tags: javascript, html, validation

this is a very basic web page. the validate part is not working in the code. On clicking submit, it is just checking for the inline validations and then directly going to the destination page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function validate()
{
    var tickt = document.form1.tickets.value;
    var child = document.form1.childrens.value;
    var date =  document.form1.showdate.value;
    var sysdate = new Date();
    var amount = (tickt - child) * 200 + child * 100;

    if (tickt < child){alert("No of tickets should be greater than the no of children"); return false;}

    else if (date < sysdate){alert("Show date and time should be either current date or future date"); return false;}

    else{alert("Your approximate ticket amount is "+amount" INR"); return true;}

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<center><h1><b>Movie Ticket Booking</b></h1></center>
<form action="thankyou.html" name="form1" onSubmit= "return (validate());">
  <table align="center">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Show date and time</td>
        <td><input name="showdate" type="datetime-local" required id="showdate"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>No of tickets</td>
        <td><input name="tickets" type="number" required id="tickets" max="10" min="1"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>No of childrens</td>
        <td><input name="childrens" type="number" required id="childrens" max="5" min="1"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input name="Book" type="submit" id="Book"  value="Book" ></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add  `preventDefault` at the top of your function to avoid the default behavior of the event (submit):

```
function validate(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault()
```

Comment: not working.   is there any way to add the function to the submit button?? i mean something on line of formaction=thankyou.html onclick=validate inside the submit tag.. will it overwrite the defaults.

Comment: so i added onclick=validate inside the submit tag and it worked. but the date check is not working. is there a way to get current date and time??

Comment: Probably the main error was you're returning `true` from your validate function, isn't it?

Comment: putting it inside submit tag is making it skip all the validation inside any other tag that is not mentioned inside the function. if i add a text input in form with pattern=[a-zA-Z\s] it skips checking the pattern and only checks the condition in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working code :

**HTML :**

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" action="thankyou.html" >
  <table align="center">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Show date and time</td>
        <td><input name="showdate" type="datetime-local" id="showdate"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>No of tickets</td>
        <td><input name="tickets" type="number" id="tickets" max="10" min="1"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>No of childrens</td>
        <td><input name="childrens" type="number" id="childrens" max="5" min="1"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input name="Book" type="submit" id="Book"  value="Book" ></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

**Javascript :**

```
var form = document.getElementById('form1')
form.onsubmit = function() {
    var tickt = document.form1.tickets.value;
    var child = document.form1.childrens.value;
    var date =  document.form1.showdate.value;
    var sysdate = new Date();
    var amount = (tickt - child) * 200 + child * 100;

    if (tickt < child) {
        alert("No of tickets should be greater than the no of children"); 
        return false;
    } else if (date < sysdate) {
        alert("Show date and time should be either current date or future date"); 
        return false;
    } else {
        alert("Show date and time should be either current date or future date"); 
        return true;
    }
}
```

You can try it on : https://jsfiddle.net/twLhfLxb/

Answer (score 0):

There was no proper closing braces inside the function. Please see the updated one.

```
        <script>
        function validate()
        {
            alert("validate");
            var tickt = document.form1.tickets.value;
            var child = document.form1.childrens.value;
            var date =  document.form1.showdate.value;
            var sysdate = new Date();
            var amount = (tickt - child) * 200 + child * 100;

            if (tickt < child){
                alert("No of tickets should be greater than the no of children"); 
            return false;
            }


            else if (date < sysdate){
                alert("Show date and time should be either current date or future date"); 
                 return false;
            }



            else 
            {
                alert("Your approximate ticket amount is "+amount+"INR"); 
                return true;


        }
        }
        </script>

        </head>
        <body>
        <center><h1><b>Movie Ticket Booking</b></h1></center>
        <form action="thankyou.html" name="form1" onsubmit="return validate()">
          <table align="center">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Show date and time</td>
                <td><input name="showdate" type="datetime-local"  id="showdate"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>No of tickets</td>
                <td><input name="tickets" type="number"  id="tickets" max="10" min="1"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>No of childrens</td>
                <td><input name="childrens" type="number"  id="childrens" max="5" min="1"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><button name="Book" type="submit" id="Book"  value="Book" >Book</button></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </form>
        </body>
```